# Admob Error : Failed to load ad

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I run my app with android studio, but my add doesn't appear...
Every time I run my app no ads appear and I get this error message in Logcat:

> "There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0 Failed to
>   load ad:0"

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MobileAds.initialize(MainActivity.this, "ca-app-pub-4760206671218452~8890405785");


    mAdview =  findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
    mAdview.loadAd(adRequest);


    mAdview.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"RKAd Loaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ad Failed to load",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ad Opened",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
            // covers the screen.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ad Left Application",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"RKAd Closed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Code to be executed when when the user is about to return
            // to the app after tapping on an ad.
        }
    });
```

Here my activity_main.xml

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="https://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4760206671218452/1505195192">

        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

I have on the screen Ad Failed to load. I created my Admob account yesterday, but the ad doesn't display :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. If your account is new please wait 2-3 Hours, it will automatically start showing ads.**

About this issue google say:

> "It could be that you have only recently created a new Ad Unit ID and
>   requesting for live ads. It could take a few hours for ads to start
>   getting served if that is that case. If you are receiving test ads
>   then your implementation is fine. Just wait a few hours and see if you
>   are able to receive live ads then. If not, can send us your Ad Unit ID
>   for us to look into."

So you have to wait for a few hours.

[Check Out Referance](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/fBe3YL3ffpo)

**2. After that if still does not started showing ads, probably you forgot to setup payment settings. So You have to complete that.**

Comment: Thanks, it's working with test ads but it's still not working with my banner. I have created my Ad Unit Id yesterday.

Comment: are you setup payment settings? if yes then please wait for some hours.

Comment: And if this answare helpfull to you, please Accept this answare as right one.

Comment: [click here](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/22/4/1527796509-payement.png) I cannot setup my payment settings

Comment: You must have to complete setup payment settings to showing add.

Answer (score 0):

i use this for testing an ad

```
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

and in the ads xml (banner test id)

```
ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
```

if you want to test your own ad you have to change the id and the tag on setRequestAgent

```
.setRequestAgent("myapp").build();
```